# How to convert a fix length char* to a number or convert a non-null terminated char* to number?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stoi

int main ()
{
  const char* arrNumber = "ff000A;";
  const std::string firstNum = std::string(arrNumber, 2);
  const std::string secondNum = std::string(arrNumber+2, 4);

  const int i_first = std::stoi(firstNum, nullptr, 16);
  const int i_second= std::stoi(secondNum, nullptr, 16);

  std::cout << "i_first: " << i_first << std::endl;
  std::cout << "i_second: " << i_second << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have two questions here.

1. How to convert a fixed-length `char*` to a number?
   In the above example, we need to extract the first two hex characters to an integer. The proposed method is slow due to the construction of a `std::string` and I am looking for a better solution similar to the following prototype.

   ```
    stoi_x(const char* start_, size_t len, int base = 10)
   ```

   Given this prototype, the above example can be written as follows:

   ```
    const int i_first = stoi_x(arrNumber, 2, 16);
   ```
2. How to convert a `char*` without null-terminator to a number?. Again, I am looking for a better solution similar to the following prototype.

   ```
    stoi_x(const char* start_, char end_, int base = 10)
   ```

   Given this prototype, the above example can be written as follows:

   ```
    const int i_second = stoi_x(arrNumber+2, ';', 16);
   ```

Comment: @SergeyA it was out of curiosity, sorry if it came across as quesitoning OPs motives

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you have non-null terminated strings?

Comment: @user463035818, some network protocols do NOT use '\0' as the terminator for a string. Instead, it only specifies the length and start of a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) and it will get you most of the way there out of the box.  It takes pointers to the beginning element and one past the last element and converts it to a number.  If it can't convert the string at all it will populate the error code in the return object otherwise it converts what it can and returns a pointer to the part of the data it couldn't convert in the return object.  Using it in your code changes it to

```
int main ()
{
    const char* arrNumber = "ff000A;";

    int i_first, i_second;
    std::from_chars(arrNumber, arrNumber + 2, i_first, 16);
    std::from_chars(arrNumber + 2, arrNumber + 6, i_second, 16); 

    std::cout << "i_first: " << i_first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i_second: " << i_second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't like that you can't assign the result of the conversion to a constant variable then you can wrap it in your own function like

```
template<typename T>
auto from_chars(char const * begin, char const * end, int base = 10)
{
    T ret{};
    std::from_chars(begin, end, ret, base);
    return ret;
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
int main ()
{
    const char* arrNumber = "ff000A;";

    const int i_first = from_chars<int>(arrNumber, arrNumber + 2, 16);
    const int i_second = from_chars<int>(arrNumber + 2, arrNumber + 6, 16);

    std::cout << "i_first: " << i_first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i_second: " << i_second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Do note I'm not doing any error handling.  In production code you should be checking if an error occurred since `std::from_chars` will not throw any exceptions.

Comment: you may consider to add a base parameter to your post since `std::from_chars` does support this and OP requires the hex conversion. Thank you

Comment: @q0987 Just did as I saw I missed it.

Comment: Learned a new feature from you today and thank you!

Comment: @q0987 You're welcome.  Glad to help.  There is also `to_chars` as the counter part to `from_chars` which is also meant to be as fast as possible.